# Where can I find all the Firefox settings?

Tags: firefox, settings

I have read from this [official article](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Prefs.js_file) that the *prefs.js* file "*does not actually contain all of the settings*." I wonder where is/are the file(s) where I can find all the settings of Firefox ? 
P.S. I am using Firefox-29.0.1 on Windows XP SP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The more complete quotation is:

> The prefs.js file does not actually contain all of the settings. It only stores changes made to the defaults

The defaults are specified in the source code, e.g. [all.js](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/modules/libpref/src/init/all.js), [firefox.js](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/app/profile/firefox.js) and others (including actual C++ code).

Also 'settings' in this context refers to preferences displayed in about:config; other settings may be stored in the [Firefox's profile folder](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data).

Why do you ask?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I need this information because I am helping my brother about his school project.

Comment: You seem to know these things, I have an other question here if you can help us: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24198685/what-are-the-changes-made-by-launching-firefox-over-prefs-js